# Ruby on Rails condition on a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, conditional-statements

Can anyone help me with a bit of code:), I have the fallowing hash

```
selector = {
 :fields => ['Id'],
 :predicates => [
   {:field => 'grpId', :operator => 'EQUALS', :values => [params_id]},
   {:field => 'CrType', :operator => 'EQUALS', :values => ['KEYWORD']}
 ]
}
```

And I would like to create a condition for this line:

```
{:field => 'grpId', :operator => 'EQUALS', :values => [params_id]},
```

to be performed only if the params_id is not empty.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selector = {
 :fields => ['Id'],
 :predicates => [
   params_id ? {:field => 'grpId', :operator => 'EQUALS', :values => [params_id]} : nil,
   {:field => 'CrType', :operator => 'EQUALS', :values => ['KEYWORD']}
 ].compact
}
```